Vercel Production Environment Returning Outdated (localhost:3000/apiCall) Data from API Endpoint
Problem:
I have a Next.js application deployed on Vercel with an API route (/api/fetchAndStoreNews) that fetches data from external sources, processes it, and stores it in a MongoDB database. The application works perfectly in my local development environment, where API calls correctly fetch and store the latest data in MongoDB, and subsequent API calls update/return this updated data.
However, in the production environment deployed on Vercel, I’m encountering a persistent issue where the API returns outdated data. Specifically:

The API responds with a 200 status code, but the data it returns is from a previous API call made during development (or the last successful localhost API call).
The data in MongoDB does not seem to be updating with new information when the production API is triggered, even though the API returns a successful (200) response.
Redeploying prod on Vercel will update the site to have the most up-to-date localhost:3000/api/fetchAndStoreNews info, whereas calling prod.com/api/fetchAndStoreNews will NEVER update values on the live site.

Steps Taken to Troubleshoot:

Environment Variables:

Verified that all environment variables (e.g., MONGODB_URI, NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL) are correctly set in Vercel’s production environment and match those used in development.
The database connection string points to the correct MongoDB instance.


Database Inspection:

Directly inspected the MongoDB database used by production to confirm that the data is not updating after the production API call.


Logging:

Added detailed logging to the API route in production, which confirms:

The API is successfully fetching new data.
The Promise.all() operation for updating/inserting data in MongoDB is executing without throwing errors.


Despite this, the data in MongoDB remains outdated.


Cache-Control:

Ensured that cache-control headers are set correctly to prevent any caching of the API response.


Testing with Unique Data:

Modified the data fetching logic to introduce a unique identifier (e.g., timestamp) in the fetched data, but the API in production still returns the outdated data.


Manual Database Update Test:

Manually updated records in the production MongoDB instance, and verified that these changes are not reflected when the API endpoint is called in production.


Force Redeployment:

Made minor changes and forced a redeployment to ensure all settings are correctly applied in production. The issue persists.



Configuration and Code:

API Route: The route is responsible for fetching data from external APIs, updating or inserting records into MongoDB, and returning the data in the response.
Database: MongoDB (Atlas), with proper connection strings verified in the Vercel environment variables.
Vercel Plan: Hobby plan, using an external service (cron-job.org) to trigger the API on a schedule. (also will note triggering it manually with prod.com/api/fetchAndStoreNews doesn't work)

Specific Behavior:

Local Environment: Works as expected; data is fetched, stored, and returned correctly.
Production Environment: API call returns outdated data, from the last successful localhost call. MongoDB data is not being updated when i call this api from prod, even though logs suggest its a 200.

Question:
What could be causing the production environment on Vercel to consistently return outdated data from an API endpoint, despite successful responses and apparently correct execution of the data-fetching and storing logic? How can I ensure that the production environment correctly updates the MongoDB data and serves the latest information?
Thanks!
TLDR:
localhost/apiCall works fine
prod/apiCall not working, additionally prod only updates with latest localhost/apiCall when Vercel is redeployed.
